# Send hot keys to logon window when not focused

Tags: python, pyautogui, hotkeys, rpa

I am working on some SAP software automation. For the automation we are using below two phases:

1. **pyautogui** - select the environment from the sap logon screen
2. **GUI Scripting** - rest of the automation starting from the login screen

The automation script is executed on a **windows VM**. In order to select the environment we are sending hot keys to press down arrow few times and press enter. This is done using pyautogui. The script works fine, when the remote desktop connection is open and active. If the remote desktop screen is minimized, these key events are not applied to the login window.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If I understand well, your question is only about **pyautogui** (when the screen is minimized), not about **SAP GUI scripting**?

Comment: Yup, GUINscripting part is working fine when it is minimized. But the pyautogui is the one troubling...:-/